# How do I upgrade my MacBook Air 2019 SSD

Tags: macbook-pro

I’d like to upgrade my Mac **SSD** to **1TB** or **2TB** [*not a iCloud storage plan]*.

Answer (score 3):

Macbooks since about 2015 have no upgradeable components, RAM & SSD are soldered.
You would need to consider external storage.

HoToGeek has a more comprehensive list - https://www.howtogeek.com/348562/can-you-upgrade-the-ram-in-your-mac/